# What sentences could be imposed on a terrorist (caught alive)?

Tags: united-states, russia, capital-punishment, terrorism

If a terrorist is caught alive, what sentence would the United States Supreme Court impose? What about the highest court in the Russian Federation?

Is it death by hanging, life imprisonment, or execution with a revolver?

Comment: By "verdict" do you mean "sentence"? A verdict is whether someone is guilty. A sentence is the punishment.

Comment: It depends on what crime the terrorist was convicted of. Despite the labels in 18 USC Ch. 113B, there is no crime of terrorism, the crimes all involve something more specific.

Comment: You might ask whether a terrorist murdering a person and a "normal" murderer killing a person will get the same punishment or different - so there is a punishment for "murder" and an added one for "terrorism". Motivation can make a difference in sentencing.

Comment: It is, of course, obvious to almost everyone but the Israelis that sentences can't be imposed upon terrorists who die before they are caught. The Israelis demolish the family homes of terrorists even if they are caught.

Answer (score 5):

In the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), the Supreme Court would not impose a sentence; it would only consider whether the trial court imposed the correct sentence, which could include a death sentence.

The U.S. Supreme Court has permitted death sentences for terrorists who have been captured alive. Most recently, the Supreme Court reinstated the death penalty for the Boston Marathon bomber in in [*United States v. Tsarnaev*, 142 S. Ct. 1024 (2022)](https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-tsarnaev-26).

I don't believe any state or the federal government uses hanging or revolvers to carry out death sentences at this point. Far more common are the electric chair, gas chambers, and lethal injections. Firing squads and hangings are technically legal [in some states](https://deathpenaltyinfo.org/executions/methods-of-execution), but I don't know that any states actually use them.

In [russia](/questions/tagged/russia), [capital punishment is unconstitutional](https://www.loc.gov/item/global-legal-monitor/2009-12-01/russia-death-penalty-ruled-unconstitutional/). When it was in practice, it was reportedly carried out by a single executioner with a handgun. [There is talk of reinstating the death penalty](https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2022/03/10/russia-quits-europes-rule-of-law-body-sparking-questions-over-death-penalty-a76854), and of course, there is reason to believe [Russia continues to carry out capital punishment extrajudicially.](https://www.newsweek.com/russians-keep-mysteriously-falling-windows-deaths-1738954)

Comment: Sliiiiight correction: Tsarnaev was not sentenced to death for terrorism but for murder.

Comment: [He was sentenced to death for terrorism](https://storage.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.mad.152629/gov.uscourts.mad.152629.1480.0.pdf) on Counts 4 and 9 of the indictment. He was also sentenced to death for murder (Counts 5, 10, 14, 15).

Comment: Also, while U.S. Supreme Court precedent generally limits the death penalty to offenses where someone has been killed for criminal acts by an adult offender, there is a narrow national security exception still outstanding in its capital punishment jurisprudence (e.g. in an espionage case or for non-deadly wartime sabotage) that could be applied to terrorism as well even if a death wasn't caused by the act. There is also a felony-murder exception: the death penalty to be imposed on a participant in a felony who did not personally kill or intend to kill when a death occurs during the felony.

Answer (score 2):

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

The maximum sentence for an act of terrorism, such as causing explosion likely to endanger life or property contrary to [section 2](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Vict/46-47/3/section/2?timeline=false) Explosive Substances Act 1883, is life imprisonment.

The [Sentencing Council](https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/offences/crown-court/item/explosive-substances-terrorism-only/)'s guidelines on "Explosive substances (terrorism only)" gives the range for these offences as:

> 3 years’ custody – Life Imprisonment (minimum term 40 years)

In theory, a [whole life order](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-prison-sentence/life-sentences#:%7E:text=A%20whole%20life%20order%20means,except%20in%20exceptional%20compassionate%20circumstances.) may be given, meaning they will...

> ..never be released from prison, except in exceptional compassionate circumstances.

The only terrorism-related whole life orders given, that I can find, all relate to Northern Irish terrorism and have since been quashed following the Good Friday Agreement (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prisoners_with_whole_life_orders))

The maximum minimum term that I have been able to find for terrorism offences is 50 years for David Copeland who was given six life sentences for his [1999 London nail bombing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_London_nail_bombings) campaign and is not due to be released until 2049 (at the earliest).

Comment: Although tagged USA and Russia, I've answered in line with: *we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions ... please tag your answer using the tag markdown: [tag: some-tag]*". From the [Help centre](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

## Legally of the listed, only lifelong imprisonment is an option in either country

### [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In the US, Terrorism is the crime that is concerned in the "*[An Act
To deter and punish terrorist acts in the United States and around the
world, to enhance law enforcement investigatory tools, and for other
purposes. <<NOTE: Oct. 26, 2001 -  [H.R. 3162]>>](https://www.congress.gov/107/plaws/publ56/PLAW-107publ56.htm)*"  aka "PATRIOT-ACT".

It dictates a couple of punishments, the longest of which is several modifications to existing laws. The longest time is **20 years.** Those are federal crimes, and you can not charge with it in state court. However, while terrorism is not punished by death penalty itself, many crimes of terrorists, such as conspiracy for murder, can be punished with the death penalty or lifelong imprisonment, and the person can be sentenced to death for those - but not for *terrorism* under the Patriot Act.

There are [other terrorism laws that contain a death penalty](https://deathpenaltyinfo.org/stories/federal-laws-providing-death-penalty), such as 18 USC 2332b, usually when the terroristic act killed people. However, in those cases, the death penalty is always to be carried out by **lethal injection.** Otherwise, **lifelong imprisonment** is an option.

[Death by firing squad](https://deathpenaltyinfo.org/executions/methods-of-execution) is only available on State Level in [mississippi](/questions/tagged/mississippi), [oklahoma](/questions/tagged/oklahoma), [utah](/questions/tagged/utah), [south-carolina](/questions/tagged/south-carolina). The latter practices Electrocution as primary method, the others lethal injection.

Hanging is/was in theory possible in [delaware](/questions/tagged/delaware), [new-hampshire](/questions/tagged/new-hampshire) and [washington](/questions/tagged/washington), but in all three lethal injection is the primary method. Atop that, you can no longer be convicted with a death penalty in New-Hampshire due to a change in law, only lingering executions can happen there. In Delaware and Washington, the Death penalty might still be on the books, but the statutes are struck down.

### [russia](/questions/tagged/russia)

There's a specific Terrorism Law in the Russian Federation, for which I could find an English translation: the  [FEDERAL LAW NO. 35-FZ OF 6 MARCH 2006 ON COUNTERACTION AGAINST TERRORISM](https://rm.coe.int/ct-legislation-russian-federation/16806415f5). It does not contain a punishment statute, but that the military is allowed to be used. There is a [2016 law](https://www.refworld.org/topic,50ffbce5220,50ffbce5226,57a43c50c,0,RFERL,,RUS.html), which is known as the [Yarovaya law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarovaya_law). It increases prison sentences, but not mandates death penalties, especially not hanging or firing squad.

While [in theory, the Death Penalty does exist in the Russian Federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_Russia), there is a [Moratorium in place since 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_Russia#Moratorium), [which was extended in 2009, when the death penalty was deemed unconstitutional](http://www.lenta.ru/news/2009/11/19/death/), and thus no new sentences can be given. Even Vladimir Putin himself said in 2013, that living the moratorium was *inadviseable*. As a result, only **Lifelong imprisonment** is at all an option for terrorism in the Russian Federation.

For the record, the [last legal execution happened in 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergey_Golovkin), after which then-president Yeltsin ordered an informal stop. The method for that last execution so far was firing a single shot into the back of the head.